# Discord.JS receiving and sending messages multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am working on writing a basic bot. For some reason, the bot responds multiple times to a single command.

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client();

const PREFIX = "+";

var fortunes = [
"Yes",
"No",
"Maybe",
" a wild swear has appeared"
];

bot.on("message", message => {

bot.on("message", function (message) {
    if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;


    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

    var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");


    switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case "ping":
            message.channel.send("Pong!")
            break;
        case "info":
            message.channel.send("no")
            break;
        case "8ball":
            if (args[1]) message.channel.sendMessage(fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)]);
            else message.channel.send("Cant read that")
            break;
        case "embed":
            var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .addField("Test Title", "test description");
            message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
            break;
        case "noticeme":
            console.log('Received #' + message.id + ': ' + message.content);
            message.channel.send(message.author.toString() + " Senpai has noticed you")
                .then(message => console.log('Sent #' + message.id + ': ' + message.content))
                .catch(console.error); 
            break;

        

    }
});
});


    bot.login("NOPE")
```

The terminal:
[image: terminal]

The code is set up to log message received and sent. Sometimes, as you can see at the top, it only runs the command once as it should. But most of the time, the command is repeated (at least) four times.

Comment: It's better to have output as text formatted within question rather than a screenshot image

Comment: Could you try running that code again? The API was a bit *unstable* earlier today

Comment: This is a glitch. Just restart the program and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this **exactly solves** the problem, but you have a message event in another message event:

```js
bot.on("message", message => {
    bot.on("message", function (message) {
       //other code here
    });
});
```

You should probably remove one of them, it doesn't really matter which one.

Answer (score 0):

`bot.on()` is an event listener. You can't set a listener in another listener.

Two listeners should be like this below, but they are same. Should remove one of them

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    //code A
});

bot.on("message", (message) => {
    //code B
});
```